# Kubernetes pod random timeout

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, containers

I have a Kubernetes deployment containing a very simple Spring Boot web application. I am experiencing random timeouts trying to connect to this application externally.

Some requests return instantly whereas others hang for minutes.

I am unable to see any issues in the logs.

When connecting to the pod directly, I am able to `curl` the application and get a response immediately so it feels more like a networking issue.

I also have other applications with the identical configuration running in the same cluster which are experiencing no problems.

I am still quite new to Kubernetes so my question would be:

Where and how should I go about diagnosing network issues?

Can provide more information if it helps.

Comment: Are you running your cluster on some cloud service, or?

Comment: Yes AWS with kops

Comment: I've experienced the similar issue (though with Azure and different app stack), workaround was deleting the pod (which was re-created by deployment/controller) which caused networking to start working properly. I'm guessing it has something to do with traffic routing, so I'll post an answer if I manage to figure out how to track it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have narrow down the issue to networking which means components of the cluster are healthy such as **Kubelet, Kube-proxy** and etc.

You can check their status by using systemctl utility. For example

```
systemctl status kubelet
systemctl status kube-proxy
```

You can get more detail by using journalctl utility. for example

```
journalctl -xeu kubelet
journalctl -f -u docker
```

Now If you want to know what's the **destiny** of the packets then you need to use iptables utility. It's the one who decides forwarding, routing, and verdict of the packets (incoming or outgoing packetes).

My plan of action is **Do Not** make any assumptions.I follow following utilities to clear the doubts.

- Kubectl

  Kubectl describe pod/svc podName/svcName
- systemctl
- journalctl
- etcdctl
- curl
- iptables

If I still could not solve the issue it means I have made an assumption.

please let me know any other tools I would love to put it on my utility-set

Comment: Ended up being a different issue but awarding to you for your help thanks